# How scan in flutter the QR code belonging to the DRIVER_LICENSES collection only and ensure that it displays an error message if it's a different?

Tags: android

So here is the page where I scan the QR code that I generate or retrieve from the internet.
if it is similar to the generated QR code, it takes me to a page with the information of this QR code; otherwise, it displays an error message.

```dart
  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    var scanArea = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 400 ||
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 400)
        ? 150.0
        : 300.0;
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          borderColor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderLength: 30,
          borderWidth: 10,
          cutOutSize: scanArea),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });

    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async{
      DocumentSnapshot qrDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('DRIVER_LICENSES')
          .doc(scanData.code)
          .get();
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
      });

      if (qrDoc != qrDoc) {
        print("Result");
        print(result!.code);
        const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("erreur lors du scan"),
        );
      } else{
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InformationPermis()));
      }
    });


  }
  }
```